# ng-grid sum and sort aggregate row

Tags: angularjs, sorting, ng-grid

Im using ng-grid and angular to show my data. When I aggregate on a column I use a function to sum all data in that group and display it.

in aggregateTemplate:

```
{{aggFunc(row, col)}}
```

in controller:

```
$scope.aggFunc = function(row, col) {
  var total = 0;
  angular.forEach(row.children, function(cropEntry) {
    total += parseFloat(cropEntry.entity[col.field]);
  });

  return total;    
};
```

Now to the problem; I use aggFunc to show the sum of several columns and I want to be able to sort columns based on the sum instead of the children in a group.

Any ideas?